# Compressing Directory tree into multiple tar archives into a single xz

Tags: tar, compression, xz

I'm trying to compress a large `rootdir` which contains many `subdir_i` the folder tree looks like:

```
./rootdir
./rootdir/subdir_1
./rootdir/subdir_2
...
```

I am looking to output this to a single compressed archive but having each subdirectory in it's own tar archive:

```
rootdir.tar.xz  # containing:
     subdir_1.tar
     subdir_2.tar
```

I've tried the following :

```
for foo in `find rootdir -maxdepth 1 -name "subdir_*" -type d`
do
     tar --create --verbose --file=- --directory="rootdir" `basename ${foo}` 
     # in shorter form:  tar -cvf - -C rootdir subdir_i
done | xz -zc9 > rootdir.tar.xz
```

Which does isolate the subdirectory into an xz but a single tar archive is inside with only the last directory:

```
rootdir.tar.xz
     rootdir.tar # containing subdir_2/
```

However the size of that archive is consistent with compression of the whole `rootdir` tree. Any ideas why that is and how to get it to do what I want (without using intermediate archives)?

Comment: I don't think `xz` files can contain more than one file, so all you get after uncompressing it is a bunch of concatenated `tar` files, and I'm not sure that's any better than just one `tar` file? What are you trying to do here? Have an easy way to extract any individual subdirectory from the final archive?

Comment: Exactly, be able to uncompress only part of the data.

Comment: @adjpayot even using only one tar you are still able to extract only part of the data. But tar is not performing best in this case. I would simply keep all the subdir tar balls separated.

Answer (score 2):

You can create `tar` files for each directory, i.e., `directory-1.tar`, `directory-2.tar`, ..., , `directory-n.tar`, then create a tar file with all the pieces and compress it by `tar Jcf whole-shebang.tar.xz directory-*.tar`.

Why do this, when you can just `tar Jcf whole-shebang.tar.xz directory-*`? You can certainly extract individual directories/files from that hairball, in your setup you'd have to first extract the specific tarball and then rummage in it to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

What your are actually doing is to concatenate all the tar balls. You can see the whole content using tar's `-i` switch:

```
$ tar -itvf rootdir.tar.xz
subdir_2/
subdir_1/
```

I don't think it's possible to create a tar ball of all these subdir tar balls directly via a pipe. You would need to write them to disk first within the loop:

```
for foo in `find rootdir -maxdepth 1 -name "subdir_*" -type d`
do
  tar --create --verbose --file=- --directory="rootdir" "$(basename ${foo})" \
  >"${foo}.tar"
done
tar -cf -  rootdir/subdir*.tar | xz -zc9 > rootdir.tar.xz
rm rootdir/subdir*.tar
```

Comment: It does seem to be all there, for some reason it isn't showing up in 7z. I need to do that simultaneously to up to 2TB of data. Making a copy is not an option.